Should we align reputation requirements for review queue access and edit privileges?
TL;DR: make the reputation needed to access review queues and to make edits the same, to spare anyone below 2,000 rep the frustration of not being able to do reviews properly.
It takes 500 reputation points to access review queues. However, it takes 2,000 reputation points to allow instant editing. As of writing, there are over 300,000 SO users in that reputation range.
These users are in a weird limbo where they are supposed to be doing reviews, but not really given all the tools. For me at least, editing is a big part of reviewing, yet I can do only up to five edits, which is frustrating. While it was suggested I just skip posts that require editing, I find this no solution:
I have to analyse the post before making the decision on whether it has to be edited. Meaning that I put effort into understanding a review item and what need to be done about it, only to end with the conclusion "I know what to do, but I'm not allowed to do anything about it". It's even more frustrating when I do edit a post, but the queue is full again and I can not submit that edit.
A potential solution? Both privileges should come in a bundle. Now be it both at 500, 1,000 or 2,000 doesn't really matter to me as a potential reviewer, as long as I can do that task properly.
Personally I would favour giving both privileges at 1,000 reputation points.
However, from what I have seen, lowering the reputation for editing privileges is something that will most likely not be agreed upon, same goes for bypassing the requirement for reviews only. So the only solution left would be to raise the reputation needed to access to the review queues to 2,000 reputation points. Though that would lose a portion of the current reviewers.
Further reading on MSE and MSE chat.

Stack Overflow puts content first as that is the key player in this site, we're all just volunteers to help sweep up. Hence it shouldn't be too hard to reason and understand why there is a higher rep requirement for editing without peer review. Editing can be a very destructive action. Understanding of the site and especially why it works the way it does, often not as you would assume, can really help to gain an understanding for such concepts as why it is vitally important to embrace hitting skip in review. And that should take away frustration.

I understand the need for putting instant edits on the high shelf, so to speak. Given that editing is a significant part of reviewing, I'd rather be given access to the reviews queues once I am trusted to do edits. (I know that many frown upon the idea of lowering the the requirement for editing. Therefore I mentioned the idea of raising the requirement for review access.) If anything, I see the editing privilege as a prerequisite to be able to do reviews. Not having that ability on reviews causes frustration despite knowing why that is and I do believe that drives people off reviews.

Although I do make edits in Staging Ground, I probably shouldn't. Editing should not be a significant part of reviewing in Staging Ground. The asker should do most of the editing, and the reviewer should direct them as to what needs editing and why. Staging Ground is the place to teach new users how to write good questions.

I am not talking about Staging Ground specifically. First answer, first question, late answer all do have valid posts that may contain fluff ("JS newbie here","i searched for hours for a solution", "thanks in advance"), the user does not how to tag/format code properly/write good english etc. An edit (and comment if needed) can fix such a post.

Yeah, the Staging Ground is the only Review Queue where we (I also have <2k-Rep) can do Edits properly, all the other Queues cause too much frustration because of the Edit Process, ... so I quickly stopped doing Reviews after reaching 500-Rep. (And I don't do (suggested) Edits either, or only very-very rarely...)

I don't think this is the right solution to this issue (which I do very much agree is a real problem)... I think this is a usability flaw with the queue(s) themselves, which should be addressed via better UI in the queues. Restricting users who can't unilaterally edit from doing reviews at all seems like it would have a pretty hefty negative impact, and only "solves" the problem insomuch as it prevents people from encountering it, rather than doing anything material to improve the review/er experience (which really needs help in more ways than this).

Related recent request: Should the review be skipped automatically if one wants to edit but the queue is full and the reviewer does not have full-edit privileges?

@zcoop98 I dont think no matter how fancy you make the UI it won't help. As stated previous times: Why should I bother reviewing if not given the tools to do so? Why analyse review items only to come to the conclusion, "I know how to fix this, but I'm not allowed to do something about it." It is just wasted time and effort from my part. While raising the access to reviews does have a negative impact, pretty much any other solution has been rejected or ignored: Lowering the edit-requierments, bypass the edit-queue limit for reviews only, allow free edits in reviews only etc.

No, we should get people used to review queues gradually rather than letting them run amok from the very first and then having to undo lots of uninformed or bad decisions.
The problem that review queues is that there are insufficient numbers of people doing reviews. Increasing the amount of rep required to participate will reduce that and make a bad situation worse. The number of people drops off quite steeply as reputation increases, for instance there are perhaps half a million people with at least 500 rep but only half that with 1000 rep. So we'd halve the number of people able to do reviews.
If you answer questions regularly it shouldn't take too long to get to 2000 reputation where you can both edit questions freely and review the edits of others. The site grants privileges gradually so that

you can get used to using each new privilege
there's a sense of achievement each time you get some new ability


I'd argue that leaving things as is leads to a situation where I and probably other users are driven away from doing reviews. Given the insufficient numbers of reviewers, isn't that a problem as well? The workaround of getting more reputation will solve the problem for me eventually, but it leaves the structural problem of few reviews. As a "low rep" user, why should I do reviews if I am not deemed fit to do so and therefore not being provided the tool for doing reviews efficently?

There are many reasons why users are driven away from the queue, @A-Tech ; the entire system is flawed. For myself, for example, in the suggested edits queue I got fed up of being asked to review edits where the suggestion simply added a tag, or added a language hint to a code fence, and didn't address any of the spelling and grammar errors; meaning I spent more time editing questions in the queue that I did actually reviewing. The real problem, surprise, is onboarding.

"If you answer questions regularly it shouldn't take too long to get to 2000 reputation" that's easy to say as a user with 123k rep. Users like me don't have the expertise to provide good answers on a regular basis. If I would post one answer each day, most of my answers would be of low quality. Does that mean my edits are bad?

BTW I agree that users should get used to using their privileges before they get new ones, but the lack of the edit privilege feels like my edit suggestions create more work for high-rep users instead of lowering their workload, which is discouraging me from suggesting more edits
